# Is there a way in Kotlin to cast a variable as the intersection of an Enum and an interface?

Tags: kotlin, enums, casting

I have the following function which defines a generic parameter that is the intersection of an Enum and an interface. The `GameConfigEnum` interface basically enforces the Enum has a `displayName` member.

`fun <E> valFromDisplayName(enum: E, displayName: String) : E 
   where E: Enum<*>, E: GameConfigEnum{
    return enum.javaClass.enumConstants.first { it.displayName == displayName }
}`

I can't find a way, however, to cast a variable as the required `enum` parameter that satisfies both `Enum<*>` and `GameConfigEnum`. Taking a snippet of the calling code:

`if(prop.value is Enum<*> && prop.value is GameConfigEnum) {
   val x = valFromDisplayName(prop.value as ??, value as String)
 }`

I need an explicit cast, and if I cast to `GameConfigEnum` it expects an `Enum<*>` and if I cast to `Enum<*>` it expects a `GameConfigEnum`. `prop.value` is satisfying the `if` statement in the invoking code.

I was trying to read up on class intersection support in Kotlin but coming up short with there being a way to cast to an intersection class.

Comment: Have you tried in the calling code to assign e. g. "val pv = prop.value" and then using "pv" in the "if"? At least theoretically the compiler could then be able to prove that the call is correct.

Comment: Interesting. If I put your pv workaround just after the if statement, linting in IntelliJ gives me the same error. If I put it just before and change the if to use pv, then I get no linting error, but in both cases, my gradle build results in the same error that "Type parameter bound for E in valFromDisplayName...is not satisfied...".

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin 1.6.21, it seems like you don't need the cast:

```
enum class GreatGameConfigEnum(override val displayName: String): GameConfigEnum {
    JOYSTICK("joystick"),
    EXAMPLE("example");
}

fun findVal(arg: Any, displayName: String): Any? {
    return if (arg is Enum<*> && arg is GameConfigEnum)
        valFromDisplayName(arg, displayName)
    else null
}

@Test
fun test() {
    val e = findVal(GreatGameConfigEnum.EXAMPLE, "joystick")
    assertEquals(GreatGameConfigEnum.JOYSTICK, e)
}
```